# Pandas dp dropping row with mutiple strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop  a row with mutiple string patterns from a csv file a single pattern works but when adding another pattern it doesn't work and does nothing to the file

ols = df[df["Risk"].str.contains("Not") == False] this works

ols = df[df["Risk"].str.contains("Not | yes") == False] this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC remove spaces in `"Not|yes"`, for compare with `False` invert mask by `~`:

```
df[~df["Risk"].str.contains("Not|yes")]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. That Space was the issue.